# Можно ли использовать один сокет в нескольких потоках?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, сокет

Клиентское приложение на C++ передаёт на HTTP-сервер данные - идентификатор клиента (чтобы обозначить присутствие), кадры с веб-камеры (по запросу), скриншоты рабочего стола (по запросу). Если можно было бы транслировать или камеру, или дисплей, то вопрос бы не стоял, но по заданию должна быть возможность одновременной трансляции.

Через клиентский сокет клиент вещает свой ID с информацией о том, может ли он использовать камеру (не у всех она есть). При ответе сервера с запросом на трансляцию камеры, десктопа, или и всего вместе клиент создаёт отдельный поток для камеры и отдельный для десктопа, так как интервалы трансляции кадров разные (если с камеры 6 кб кадр можно слать 20-25 раз в секунду, то 300 кб дисплей не более 2-х, чтобы сеть не перегружать).

И вот у меня творческий тупик из-за возможно неполного понимания работы сокетов: **Можно ли для этих потоков использовать один сокет?** Объёмы данных приличные, не будут они друг другу мешать на одном сокете при `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`?

Comment: А сами-то вы как думаете? :)

Comment: Я подозреваю, что придётся отдельные сокеты делать, но может всё-таки этого не надо? :) Может я не всё про сокеты знаю, вот и прошу подсказки... :))

Comment: Если правильно и аккуратно -то можно. Более того, так даже делают. Главное, все синхронизировать, что бы не смешивалось. А на стороне сервера нужно будет сделать обратную процедуру - разложить поток на два.

Comment: Ещё одна деталь - в каждом потоке заголовки будут отличаться. Для сервера не проблема по заголовкам раскидать данные в свои участки распределяемой памяти. Мне главное, чтобы клиент всё корректно отправлял и не мешал данные. Если одновременно через сокет пойдёт кадр с камеры и с десктопа, не получится ли так,что на сервер попадёт один смешанный бинарник?

Comment: @KoVadim в голову мысль пришла, а что если написать класс сокета, а потом создать класс с помощью множественного наследования класса потока и класс сокета. что получится? )

Comment: HTTP/2 умеет мультиплексировать несколько запросов в одно соединение. Это заложено в протокол.

Comment: @perfect наследование ещё не умеет делать автоматический магический мютекс

Comment: Я так понял, проще и надёжней сделать три сокета на один адрес, да?

Comment: далеко не факт, что проще сделать три сокета. Кол-во сокетов на сервере хоть и большое, но не бесконечное.

Comment: Ну, клиентов не больше сотни будет, а обычно вообще до 50. Потянет сервер 300 сокетов под постоянной полной нагрузкой?

Comment: если все правильно напишите, то может и потянет.  По сокетам вряд ли будет затык. В Вашем случае скорее всего затык может быть по I/O (сетевой и/или дисковый).

Comment: Диск не используется на сервере - всё в shared memory, так как некогда файлы читать при таком потоке информации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понял что имеется в виду под отдельными потоками на клиенте, если поток это отдельное соединение к серверу, то у вас собственно и должно быть по сокету на конект/поток, ну а если все данные идут по одному каналу, то и нужен 1 сокет, то есть вам нужно отталкиваться от архитектуры клиента, а другого выбора то и нет.
В любом случае у вас буден один мастер-сокет ждущий подключения, который будет создавать новые слэйв-сокеты на каждый конект. Если есть возможность создавать по сокету на "поток", то лучше так и делайте, select/epoll и т.п. в помощь. Среднестатистический ПК в состоянии работать с десятками тысяч сокетов одновременно, спокойно читая/отправляя гигабиты/с.

sitev_ru - что-то вы не понятное написали вообще, сколько одновременных запросов может отправлять "сайтик" зависит от браузера, по дефолту в современных браузерах это 6-8 одновременных запросов при HTTP /1.1.

Comment: Спасибо за совет

Answer (score -1):

Клиентское приложение на C++ - это socket-клиент, а HTTP-сервер - это socket-сервер. Это нормально, если несколько клиентов цепляются на один сервер...

Ответ: много socket-клиентов и один socket-сервер

P.S. Средненький сайтик можен отправлять HTTP-серверу до нескольких десятков или даже сотен запросов одновременно. Это всякие картиночки, js- скрипты и т.д.